# substr_replace and substr to get last char return �

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I tried:

```
substr($string, 0, -1);
substr_replace($string ,"",-1);
```

but get always

> �

and not the last char of my string????

I want to compare strings and the last Char of stringTwo always is missing, so i tried to find equal stings with substr_replace or substr function and deleting the last char.

$stringOne = "house";

$stringTwo = "hous";

it is strange again and again i get �� by using substring and substr_replace... with mb_substr i can delete the �, but how can i check before doing something if i use mb_substr or substr???

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to manipulate the string or just return the last character?

Comment: What is the last character? Maybe it is a multibyte character you are cutting it in half? Maybe try http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Comment: i updated my question... it is strange again and again i get �� by using substring and substr_replace... with mb_substr i can delete the �, but how can i check before doing something if i use mb_substr or substr???

Comment: `echo substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"` may you should look here: http://php.net/substr

Comment: Can you provide a full code example of the issue?

Comment: @ma-jo-ne, what is your **real question**? What are you really trying to achieve, some kind of word search tool? Anyways you can compare using **`if`** used with some **OR** `||` operators.

Answer (score 1):

if you're dealing with ascii/bytes, get the last byte like

```
$last=substr($string,-1,1);
```

but if your string is is unicode, it gets slightly more complicated, use mb_substr, with the encoding as last paramter, for instance for UTF-8:

```
$last=mb_substr($string,-1,1,'UTF-8');
```

-- note that mbstring has been bugged for a long time, and i have personally experienced it failing on some smileys for a long time (from 5.4 up to 5.6~ at least, with up to date mbstring from dotdeb.. where it would just get 2 or 3 bytes of the 4 bytes used to make them in utf-8 - unfortunately i dont have any samples ready... anyone?)

Answer (score 0):

To get the last character of a string just use the [substr method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). The substr parameters are `substr(string $string, int $start, [,int $length])`.

This should get the last character:

```
echo substr($string, -1, 1);
```

To compare two strings, where the last character is removed from $stringTwo, you can use the following:

```
if($stringTwo == substr($stringOne, 0, -1)){}
```

Comment: it is strange again and again i get �� by using substring and substr_replace... with mb_substr i can delete the �, but how can i check before doing something if i use mb_substr or substr???

Comment: If your goal is to compare the strings, any string manipulation shouldn't be required. Just compare which parts of the strings you want.

Comment: Are you saying `substr($stringOne, 0, -1)` returns "�"?

Comment: no. if i pr($stringOne) the output is normal.... but if try to delete the last char with substr($stringOne, 0, -1) its the same string, but at the end two ��

Comment: substr doesn't alter / manipulate a string... It simply returns the substring. If you want to actually remove a character you'd need to do `$stringOne = substr($stringOne, 0, -1);`

Comment: pr($stringOne); after doing that returns House��, but i wand "Hous"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104819/discussion-between-ma-jo-ne-and-devon-bernard).